Get the Post view count when scroll to a post or view a post vue js?
I have a page listing all the posts one by one. I want to add a count post_view incremented by 1 when the user scrolls to a post or views a post. I am kind of confused about what should be the scroll behavior I should add here ?
Here is what I want .. 
What will be the scroll behavior when I am viewing a post or focusing on a post?

You need to add some code that you have tried to achieve the same.

I recommend migrating toward VueJS/NuxtJS 3 first, then you could use a mix of useWindowScroll as explained here or useIntersectionObserver depending on how you want to manage it. You could overall have an array that you populate with all of the articles already shown and increment the counter based on the length of that array. Overall, any code progress on your side is welcome.
